# treemacs error window keeps growing in size

Tags: lsp-mode, treemacs

I recently started using `lsp-treemacs` and I mostly like it.  It would be nice if it auto-jumped to the file for the current buffer, but I can work around that.

However, the biggest complaint that I have with it is that the buffer keeps growing.  When I first launch it, it tends to be about 1/4 of the screen height, which in my set up is about 14 lines.  That is reasonable, especially since there are 9 different projects "loaded" into Emacs.

After I edit a bit, the buffer will grow to about half the screen height.  This cuts down on how much I can see in the buffers where I am editing files, and the only return is a lot of empty space in the treemacs buffer.

Inserting or deleted an open parenthesis `(` causes the resize.  I'm not sure if there are other actions that also cause it.  `(` is bound to `self-insert-key` and backspace is bound to `delete-backward-char`.

I am running `lsp-metals` and `lsp-ui`.

Is there a way to stop the buffer from growing vertically?